# NestJS + Sequileze дает не правильное время

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, nestjs, sequelize.js

[image: В базе данных Postgres]
С помощью NestJs и Sequelize заполняю поля в postgres и автоматически добавляется поля createdAt и updatedAt
Время на севере стоит верное (+3), время на сервере тоже +3.
В postgres время отображается коорректно, однако при попытке вывести данные, он выдаёт время -3 часа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понятно где искать ошибку, потому что везде время стоит верное, но по факту на выходе получаем -3 часа.

Исходник сервера https://github.com/MishaJSR/serverTs

Comment: нет никакой ошибки. время в utc

Comment: Тогда почему node даёт время без utc?